# Access the store from a model's static (aka class-level) method?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've got this:

```
Post.reopenClass({
  myStaticMethod: function() {
    // I need to access the store here!
    // this.store => undefined
  }
});
```

PS Why can't i just import the store or something?

Comment: Are you trying to get access to another model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the model class is not connected to a particular store. Stores hold instances of models, not model classes. Model instances are created from a store via `store.createRecord(model...`, and the resulting instances are placed in that store. So in theory, you could have instances of the same model class in different stores.

If you really want access to the store, you could do a container lookup (code smell). Or, you could arrange to pass in the store as a parameter to `myStaticMethod` if possible (better).

I assume perhaps you want to access the store from a static method because you're want to create a record, or find one, or something. Let's say you wanted to write a variant of `createRecord` which did something special. The obvious way to approach that would be to add it to the main store, or possibly put it in a subclass of `DS.Store`, and invoke it as `store.createRecordSpecial('model', ...`.

Comment: Thank you, torazaburo. Your assumption is correct: i want a customized `createRecord`. The difficulty is that it should be a promise (`store.find`). But i've figured that i don't need the record to appear immediately instantiated. So instead of using a static method on the model, i'm going to do `store.createRecord('foo').customize()`. The record will appear non-customized but then will customize itself when the promise resolves. I think it's fine.